# Pull Customers Who Have Not Opened or Clicked

Tags: query

I'm trying to write a sql query to pull a list of customers who have not opened or clicked an email within the last 360 days. How do I go about writing this? I want this for any email send (haven't opened or clicked ANY emails from us).

Answer (score -1):

you can query like this with your condition

```
 Select Name, AccountId, (Select Id, EmailTemplateName From EmailStatuses ) From Contact
```

put your condition in WHERE clause inside the sub query.